1. Men value physical attractiveness more than Women when dating. 2. Men are more likely to have casual sex than Women. How about for Transgender?

It is a common sense that men statistically place much more important on physical attractiveness when dating, no matter whether they are heterosexual or homosexual:

1

It is also a common sense that men statistically are much more likely than women to accept an offer of casual sex. Men are also less picky than Women with a potential sex partner/when dating, no matter whether they are heterosexual or homosexual:

2
There are still very few studies about transgender (extremely under-researched). Any related studies of point 1 and 2 about transgender (FTM/ MTF)? Statistically do they resemble biological/post-oped gender more?
